# How do I update values in JSP with servlet?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, server

I have a calendar which allows the user to select dates and there will be a counter. Whenever the user checks a box, the value of the count will increase and this is done using jquery.

```
 <td colspan="7"> 
   You need <%=myCourse.getTotalNoClass()%> classes
    <input type="hidden" value="<%=myCourse.getTotalNoClass()%>" id="myCourse" name="classCount">
    </br> No of Classes selected: 
    <b><input type="text" id="count-class" name="selectedClass" value="<%=session.getAttribute("selectedClass") %>"></b>
</td>
```

I want the count value to be shown on the same page after the user clicks a submit button, and as they continue to check boxes, the value of count will continue to increase until they reach the maximum.

**Example in Servlet:**

```
if(classCount == classSelect){
    request.getRequestDispatcher("confirm-schedule.jsp").forward(request,response);
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("schedule.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

Basically my problem is i am not sure how to update the `value="<%=session.getAttribute("selectedClass") %>"` as jquery will affect it.
The value is able to be stored, but the jquery keeps starting the count on 0. how do i do make sure that the jquery starts count on the value in `value="<%=session.getAttribute("selectedClass") %>"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitDates").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

 $("input[name=date]").change(function(){
var max= $("#myCourse").val();

if( $("input[name=date]:checked").length == max ){

    $("input[name=date]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#submitDates").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("input[name=date]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');

}else{

     $("input[name=date]").removeAttr('disabled');
}
});

 var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
          $("#count-class").val( n );
        };

    countChecked()
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );

});
```

Comment: `request.setParameter("paramname",value)` or use session varieble

Comment: thank you @SumeshTG, i hope you can help me with my next problem

Answer (score 0):

Just set the counter in your servlet using

```
request.setParameter("nameOfYourParameter","theValueYouWantToSet");
```